# How do you pass awk variable in scientific notation

Tags: linux, variables, awk

I am trying to pass several variables to an awk command, and one of them I cannot seem to be able to pass because it is in scientific notation like this:

```
r=20 # This is a column in the file I would like to print if the condition is true (if the first column is less than the value specified in $a)
a=1e-012
```

This works:

```
awk -v r=$r '{OFS=FS="\t"} {if ($1 < 1e-012) print $r}' file.txt
```

This doesn't:

```
awk -v r=$r -v a=$a '{OFS=FS="\t"} {if ($1 < $a) print $r}' file.txt
```

How can I make sure this variable is passed correctly?

Thank you for your help

Comment: you can try `awk -v r=$r -v a=$a '{OFS=FS="\t"} {if ($1 < a) print r}' file.txt`

Comment: variables in awk script without symbol `$`

Comment: Good trouble shooting tip here would be to print out just the variable value to see what's actually getting passed into the awk script: `awk -v r=$r -v a=$a '{ print $a }' file.txt`  You would see pretty quickly that `$a` isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: Thank you Jose and JNevil!! I thought all needed to be within the dollar symbol!

Comment: In awk, think of the `$` in `$x` as an *operator* to fetch the value of the column named by the variable `x`